# Zero-width space and <wbr> have no effect on Japanese line-breaking

Tags: html, unicode, cjk

As I understand it from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr), `<wbr>` and the Unicode zero-width space character, `&ZeroWidthSpace;` or `&#8203;`, are functionally equivalent, and are supposed to suggest line-break opportunities, especially for languages such as Japanese that do not use spaces as word boundaries.

Nevertheless, all modern browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari seem to completely ignore them when deciding where to break a line of Japanese text. I know that technically it is not supposed to matter where a line break occurs in Japanese, but our translators have asked whether we could improve where some line-breaks are occurring.

Here is a JSFiddle which demonstrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/520khpzg/

And here is the same as standalone HTML:

```
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing Line Breakks in Japanese</title>
  <style>
    div {
      font-size: 2rem;
      width: 12rem;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    デバイス<wbr>設定方法
  </div>
  <div>
    デバイス&#8203;設定方法
  </div>
  <div>
    aaaaaa<wbr>bbbbbb
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I must be missing something fundamental here, but having read over various docs I’ve no idea what it could be. Why would browsers ignore `<wbr>` and `&#8203;` in Japanese but not in English, particularly when the Unicode documentation for ZWSP suggests that it is precisely for languages like Japanese?

Comment: Not a solution, but a comment: maybe the CSS properties line-break or word-break will help for your use case?

Comment: @LokiRagnarok thanks for the comment, yes, they might do, but in my tests I tried lots of different values for both those properties and they didn't seem to make any difference at all except for `word-break: break-all` which forced line breaks at the instances of `<wbr>` or `&#8203;` even when they weren't needed.

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting in this case? By default line breaks are allowed between all Kanji and (full-size) Katakana characters, so adding ZWSP or <wbr> doesn’t change anything. From the perspective of a writing system with more strict line break rules (e.g. Latin), Japanese characters behave as if they’re interspersed with ZWSP already.

Comment: @CharlotteBuff thank you, that may well be exactly what I was not understanding before. I thought that ZWSP or `<wbr>` would indicate a line break preference. But if as you say effectively all Japanese characters "behave as as if they're interspersed with ZWSP already" then I understand why it wouldn't do what I was hoping. Perhaps you should add that as the answer? I can't be alone in not realising this was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilising ZWSP or `<wbr>` to fine-tune line break behaviour was the right call, but there was one ingredient missing: The `word-break` CSS property.

By default, the three Japanese scripts – Kanji, Hiragana, and Katakana – allow line breaks almost everywhere, even within words. Exceptions are small kana (i.e. the ゃ in きゃ), certain punctuation marks, and a handful of symbols like 々, none of which can usually start a line.

To override this behaviour, `word-break: keep-all` needs to be used. This removes line break opportunities between Japanese (and also Chinese and Korean) characters, so lines will only wrap where some other opportunity like ZWSP is provided.

Comment: Thank you. This is invaluable information that I hope benefits a great many people.

Comment: Although, if it gets out of the experimental stage, `word-break: auto-phrase` may be a better solution.